# Redirect page through ajax call

Tags: ajax

I am sending form with fields email and password through ajax request.if they do not match i am getting response 'username and password is not correct' in Div id.If name and password match page should be redirect to another page.But i am getting whole page in same div id.I want if password and name match than page redirect to another page and if password and name not match than it give the response in same id.

Answer (score 0):

Why not have your webapp redirect to a different page instead of relying on ajax?

Comment: I want response name and password does not match without refreshing page thats why i am using ajax.

Answer (score 0):

After loading (onload/onComplete (prototypejs)/done (jQuery)) you can simply check the div (or responseText) if it contains `username and password is not correct`. If not (e.g. with indexOf), simply `window.location.href = 'loggedin.php';`.